# Build wxWidgets 2.8.12 GCC 4.6.2

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets

I am getting this error when building wxWidgets in Cygwin:

```
../src/generic/dirctrlg.cpp:67:24: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [corelib_dirctrlg.o] Error 1
T_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXDEBUG__ -I/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-2.8.12/build-debug/lib/wx/include/msw-ansi-debug-static-2.8 -I../include -Wall -Wundef -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -ggdb -O0 ../src/generic/dirctrlg.cpp
Makefile:28340: recipe for target `corelib_dirctrlg.o' failed
```

I followed the instructions included in wxWidgets for Windows using `configure` in `install.txt`(Compiling wxWidgets).

Comment: Where is the file direct.h?  Is the file in one of the folders you have included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which compiler do you use? See http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2011/06/choosing-gcc-for-building-wxwidgets.html for some of the choices you have. FWIW `direct.h` should be present in MinGW compiler headers.